# python selenium error: TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tags: python, selenium, timeoutexception

anyone know how to fix this error?
Chromedriver version is 89.0

It always fails at driver.get() that is within a loop

Sometimes the error doesn't occur for a day, sometime it will pop up within an hour

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\vsc\project1\###AAAV2.py", line 57, in <module>
  driver.get(thislist[i])

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from 
renderer: -0.000
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.128)
```

Comment: can you post the relevant code?  its impossible for us to tell what could be wrong without seeing it

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply.
Sorry that I just found a thread explaining this. I am testing out if it will help, but it will take sometime as the error comes within a day or two. I ll close this thread for now, thank you for the reply.